# AMPL: Syntax for sets?

Tags: set, ampl

I'm spinning up on high level language for mixed integer linear programs (MILPs).  The language is A Modeling Language for A Mathematical Programming Language [(AMPL)](http://ampl.com/resources/the-ampl-book/chapter-downloads).

Chapter 4, page 65, Figure 4-7 shows the following syntax:

```
set PROD := bands coils plate ;
```

However, Chapter 5, page 74, shows the following syntax:

```
set PROD = {"bands", "coils", "plate"};
```

Can anyone please explain this difference in syntax?

I put the latter into a *.dat file, and AMPL complains `expected ; ( : or symbol` where the `{` is.  Wondering if it is just a mistake in the manual.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in Chapter 4 --

```
set PROD := bands coils plate;
```

-- is used in data files, while the syntax in Chapter 5 --

```
set PROD = {"bands", "coils", "plate"};
```

-- is used in model files. It's a little weird (IMO) that the syntax for sets is different in model and data files, but it is. For another example of this difference, see [this question and answer](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/153/38).

**Complete working example code modified from AMPL manual**

Added by the original poster of the question.

`dietu.mod:`

```
# dietu.mod
#----------
# set MINREQ;   # nutrients with minimum requirements
# set MAXREQ;   # nutrients with maximum requirements
set MINREQ = {"A", "B1", "B2", "C", "CAL"};
set MAXREQ = {"A", "NA", "CAL"};

set NUTR = MINREQ union MAXREQ;    # nutrients
set FOOD;                          # foods

param cost {FOOD} > 0;
param f_min {FOOD} >= 0;
param f_max {j in FOOD} >= f_min[j];

param n_min {MINREQ} >= 0;
param n_max {MAXREQ} >= 0;

param amt {NUTR,FOOD} >= 0;

var Buy {j in FOOD} >= f_min[j], <= f_max[j];

minimize Total_Cost:  sum {j in FOOD} cost[j] * Buy[j];

subject to Diet_Min {i in MINREQ}:
   sum {j in FOOD} amt[i,j] * Buy[j] >= n_min[i];

subject to Diet_Max {i in MAXREQ}:
   sum {j in FOOD} amt[i,j] * Buy[j] <= n_max[i];
```

The explicit definitions of setes `MINREQ` and `MAXREQ` and their members is taken from the *.dat file below (where their definitions have been commented out).  Matlab users, observe above & beware that you need commas between members in a set.

`dietu.dat:`

```
# dietu.dat
#----------
data;

# set MINREQ := A B1 B2 C CAL ;
# set MAXREQ := A NA CAL ;
set FOOD := BEEF CHK FISH HAM MCH MTL SPG TUR ;

param:   cost  f_min  f_max :=
  BEEF   3.19    2     10 
  CHK    2.59    2     10 
  FISH   2.29    2     10 
  HAM    2.89    2     10 
  MCH    1.89    2     10 
  MTL    1.99    2     10 
  SPG    1.99    2     10 
  TUR    2.49    2     10  ;

param:   n_min  n_max :=
   A      700   20000
   C      700       .
   B1       0       .
   B2       0       .
   NA       .   50000
   CAL  16000   24000 ;

param amt (tr):   A    C   B1   B2    NA   CAL :=
          BEEF   60   20   10   15   938   295
          CHK     8    0   20   20  2180   770
          FISH    8   10   15   10   945   440
          HAM    40   40   35   10   278   430
          MCH    15   35   15   15  1182   315
          MTL    70   30   15   15   896   400
          SPG    25   50   25   15  1329   370
          TUR    60   20   15   10  1397   450 ;
```

Solve the model using the following at the AMPL prompt:

```
reset data;
reset;
model dietu.mod;
data dietu.dat;
solve;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  And cool!  An OR SE !!  I'm not sure whether to send all my colleagues here, as it is in beta ??  I've mostly made do with tool language SEs, Stats, Math, and computer-ish SEs.  And a grouples forum too...too many choices.  Frankly, based on computational language SEs, I find that different questions get answered on Grouples vs. SE, and I haven't yet recognized a pattern that distinguishes the types of questions that are likely to be answered in each.  P.S. And yes, it is odd that multiple syntaxes are used depending on whether it is in a *.dat or *.mod file.

Comment: The 2 methods of defining `set PROD` are confusing. In the 1st, the members are like enumerated types. The names are only used to distinguish members. They could be anything, as long as we use them consistently. They are like source code identifiers (variable names). In the 2nd syntax, they are bonafied strings, on which string functions like regular expressions can be applied. Only in weakly typed languages like Matlab have I seen the two types blur together, e.g., using strings to search for object property names. I think that using multiple syntaxes makes a language more complicated.

Comment: For example, in Chapter 6 (Compound Sets and Indexing) page 91, example code is given using quotes around strings. The context is *not* given.  Based on your answer, it seems that we should be assuming that this illustrates code in a model file.  And we *assume* that there is some other syntax in a data file.  Without knowing AMPL better, this seems to create the hazard where a set member name is confused with a variable (or rather, a parameter) name.

Comment: @user36800 I agree the change in syntax is confusing. But I think both methods are treating the elements of `PROD` as strings. For example, I used `set PROD := bands coils plate;` in a `dat` file and then did `display {p in PROD} substr(p, 2, 4);` at the command line, which produced correct results.

Comment: @user36800 As for OR.SE -- yes, please feel free to send colleagues to or.stackexchange.com, even though it is in beta. Beta is a funny designation and sites can stay in beta for many years, but still be fully in the swing of things. OR.SE is in "private beta", which is a little bit more of a "warm-up period", but it should be in public beta in a couple of weeks. I agree, too many choices, which is one reason we created OR.SE.

Comment: If it's private, can anyone access it and participate?  I usually log in using my Google account.  I'm not sure what kind of limitation on participation applies to a beta SE.

Comment: @user36800 Yes -- anyone can participate. At first it defaulted to people who had signed up on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892/operations-research), but others can join by invitation, and I think simply by going to the URL and clicking "log in". If you can't get in for some reason, ping me and I can send you an invitation. Then you can invite others.

Comment: Thanks, LarrySnyder610.

Comment: Noting that set members can be strings with spaces in them; in a .dat quotes are optional for single-word set members but required for those which contain spaces. Annoyingly, a `display` command will show quotes for the latter but not the former, making the output look inconsistent.

Comment: @ Geoffrey Bent: Thanks so much for that clarification!  I am baffled by the decision to support different syntax.  It's probably specified in the AMPL manual (the annex part of the AMPL book), but just based on plumbing the text for ordered sets, I just can't decipher its specifications.

Comment: @user36800 Yeah, it caused me a lot of confusion when I was starting out. My best guess is that .dat format is intended to minimize the need for input wrangling (e.g. I can just C&P from a spreadsheet, add a couple of lines at top and bottom and have a valid .dat without having to edit every line) but that's purely speculation.

Comment: @Geoffrey Brent: That actually makes a lot of sense.  Gives me a positive appreciation for the difference.  Thanks.